Why does this function throw a "std::bad_any_cast"
I am using C++ 17, the following code throws a std::bad_any_cast exception.
The message printed:
Current type in m_any: St8functionIFSt3anyP7ContextEE
Function type: St8functionIFSt3anyRP7ContextEE

The message indicates that m_any stores a type of Context*, yet when compute(Context*) is called, it treats context as Context*&.
template<typename Ret>
class AnyCallableF {
public:
    AnyCallableF() = default;

    template<typename F>
    AnyCallableF(F&& fun) : AnyCallableF(std::function(std::forward<F>(fun))) {}

    template<typename ... Args>
    AnyCallableF(std::function<Ret(Args...)> fun) : m_any(fun) {}

    template<typename ... Args>
    Ret operator()(Args&& ... args)
    {
        std::cout << "Current type in m_any: " << m_any.type().name() << endl;
        std::cout << "Function type: " << typeid(std::function<Ret(Args&&...)>).name() << endl;
        return std::invoke(std::any_cast<std::function<Ret(Args...)>&>(m_any), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

private:
    std::any m_any;
};

struct Context {
    int a = 0;
};

std::any getValue(Context* ctx) {
    std::any v;
    return v;
}

void compute(Context* ctx) {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, AnyCallableF<std::any>> method_map;
    method_map["getValue"] = &getValue;
    std::any value = method_map["getValue"](ctx);
}

int main() {
    Context ctx;
    compute(&ctx);
}

However, when I modify the code as shown below, it executes successfully without errors.:
int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, AnyCallableF<std::any>> method_map;
    method_map["getValue"] = &getValue;
    Context ctx;
    std::any value = method_map["getValue"](&ctx);
}

The message printed:
Current type in m_any: St8functionIFSt3anyP7ContextEE
Function type: St8functionIFSt3anyOP7ContextEE

Why they are different?

&ctx is a rvalue expression. ctx is a lvalue expression. So one time you deduce Args to Context* and one time to Context*&. The latter is not matching the original type.

There is no point in using std::any here. std::function already provides all of the necessary functionality of type erasure. std::any doesn't allow you to do anything that std::function couldn't. If you try to use two different std::function signatures with your class, it will necessarily fail to compile.

The reason why I use std::any as return type is that I may need to stores many functions with different return type in one map. Is there a better way to do it?

This doesn't work, even in principle. There is no way for the compiler to be able to check whether any type that you are trying to store somewhere in the map can be called with the expected type at the call site, except when you apriori limit the number of types to a known finite set. Can you show an example of how you would expect this to be used and why?

Also, I assume you meant "parameters", not "return type". The return type is fixed in your code.

please do not strip off includes from code. This is what happens when I try to reproduce the error: https://godbolt.org/z/4b9fKo6o5.

Although I am still not sure how exactly this should be used, to fix the mistake I mentioned above: You need to explicitly specify the function parameters in each call, matching exactly with the types that were used to store the callable. You can't rely on argument deduction. Usually types do not match exactly (e.g. value category differs). So, the call has to look something like method_map["getValue"].call<Context*>(ctx) instead of method_map["getValue"](&ctx) and call then should have a Args... function parameter instead of Args&&....

@user17732522 it does work, it's just incredibly fragile. As demonstrated by this question

You can also fix it with a by-value cast: std::any_cast<std::function<Ret(Args...)>>

Similarly std::function<Ret(Args&&...)> is different to std::function<Ret(Args...)>

To clarify my previous comment: What is impossible is to make it work with the automatic deduction in such a way that you can pass arbitrary arguments that the stored function would have accepted as well. If you only want to be able to call the functions with the exact parameter types, then it does work. But still, I haven't come across a use case for this that wouldn't be solved better in a different way.
